# Get all the elements that start with a particular innerHTML using query selector?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, selectors-api

I am currently having problem with selecting and matching the innerHTML using querySelectorAll.

Here is what i did:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[class^="js-display-url"]').contains('product')
```

What the html is:

```
<span class="js-display-url">product/poss/newslanges</span>
```

But i want to match the class js-display-url starting with product but can't do that. please help.

Comment: There are no DOM selectors which look at text nodes inside elements.

Comment: so how can i check for innerHTML any other way other that what i tried. there are a lot of elements that start with product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With DOM selectors you cannot select elements based on the inner HTML, but you can loop through all the elements with that class and single out the ones that match your condition:

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*[class^="js-display-url"]');
var myElements = [];

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) { 
    if (allElements[i].innerHTML.startsWith('product')) {
        myElements.push(allElements[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a DOM selector which will filter based on text nodes, but you can filter using some array methods, since a `NodeList` is array-like.

In particular, [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can get the elements that meet your criteria.

```js
var filter = Array.prototype.filter;

var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.js-display-url');
var productElements = filter.call(allElements, function(element) {
    return element.innerText.startsWith('product');
});

console.log(productElements);
```

```html
<span class="js-display-url">product/poss/newslanges</span>
```